# Hexo command hexo d stop after copying files to .deploy

Tags: git, github, hexo

I was trying to upload my hexo to github page.

```
$ hexo g -d
INFO  Validating config 
Inferno is in development mode.
INFO  === Checking package dependencies ===
INFO  === Checking theme configurations ===
INFO  === Registering Hexo extensions ===
INFO  Start processing
INFO  Files loaded in 740 ms
INFO  0 files generated in 182 ms
INFO  Deploying: git
INFO  Clearing .deploy_git folder...
INFO  Copying files from public folder...
```

Then it will stop here without reporting any errors. Nothing is upload to my github repo.I can see the latest docs in .deploy_git. And I found that I can use 'git push' inside .deploy_git to upload to my repo.

I'm pretty sure that I add space after each colon in _config.yml. And the link is definitely correct. Is there any idea about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Run :

```
npm un hexo-deployer-git
npm i hexojs/hexo-deployer-git
```

https://github.com/hexojs/hexo/issues/4634

The test is effective

Comment: Thanks. I tried to reinstall again today. It works even I didn't use your commands. It seems the problem is casued by hexo or github or something else.....